# Django, Effective way to redirect URL

Tags: django

When a DOM change occurs, a Javascript function fires and redirect to the same website's page with certain parameters.

From the performance point of view, is the below method right?

```
const fire=(arg)=>{
        
        location.href = '/admin/arg/';

}
```

Or should I use the `{% URL 'path' %}` tag ? if so, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The {% url 'name' %} is obviously less efficient than calling the absolute url, but it's not going to break the bank rendering your html. What difference is it going to make? A few milliseconds?